# Android build ant + .bat is not executing all commands

Tags: android, ant, batch-file

I'm developing a script to build android project which referencing lib-project so there is some preparations before launching ant, so I decided put that actions into a **.bat-file**.

The **.bat's structure** is like the following:

```
    1 - #some preparation actions (moving files, updating properties etc.)
    2 - ant debug
    3 - #clean everything that was done in the first section
```

So, the problem is that nothing is executed after the second section - **'ant debug'** - though build was successful.

Can anybody shed some light on what am I doing wrong and how to make the script after **ant debug**-command be executed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
...
call ant ...
...
```